# Error while using rarecurve() in R

Tags: r, rstudio, vegan

I am using vegan::rarecurve on community data.

```
lac.com.data<-wisconsin(lac.com.data)
rarecurve(lac.com.data)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error and cannot figure out how to fix it.

> Error in seq.default(1, tot[i], by = step) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

I tried

```
 rarecurve(lac.com.data,step=1)
```

to no avail.

I already generated a tabasco() graph and performed a Wisconsin standardization on the data frame without any problem.

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reproducible example. However, your usage is wrong. Function `rarecurve` needs input data of counts: it samples individuals from each sampling unit (row), and therefore you must have data on individuals. The error is caused by the use of `wisconsin(lac.com.data)`: after that all `rowSums(lac.com.data)` will be `1`, and your data are non-integers. You cannot use `rarecurve` for `wisconsin()` transformed data or any other non-integer data. Here the error manifests because the estimated numbers of individuals (rowSums of transformed data which are all 1) are lower than the number of species (>1).

Obviously we need to check input in `rarecurve`. We assumed that people would know what kind input is needed, but we were wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jari.  I tried running it without the Wisconsin standardization (ie on a raw contingency matrix of integer counts) and ran into the same problem.  Is there an efficient way to upload a large contingency table so that I can show what my lac.com.data dataframe looks like?

Comment: Nothing in your message points to the problems with the *size* of the input matrix. You really should try to make a *minimal* example that fails. I bet that if you make such a minimal example, you can identify the problem yourself. So please try. If you get *exactly* the same error message as in your matrix, then I see two potential problems: you really do have non-integer data, or you have empty observations (some `rowSums` are zero). If you got some other error message, then the problem may be different. I don't know because you don't tell.

Comment: Thank you.  It was because I had a few rows that summed to zero.

I wasn't suggesting that the size of the matrix was causing the function to fail.  I merely wanted to show you the dataframe I was using that was causing the problem.  However, I don't know/want to post a 51x54 dataframe on here and was asking, for future knowledge, how to do so in an efficient manner so that potential responders can see the input without having a large, awkwardly formatted dataframe in the text of my initial question.

Comment: I now see the link MrFlick linked to, which was very helpful.  My one issue is to say that if I had merely selected some of the rows, or chosen appropriate data, then the error probably would not have appeared as it did when I ran the whole dataframe, given that only two rows were all zeros.  Nevertheless, Jari was able to solve my problem.  Thanks all.

Comment: Jari, I was hoping you could answer one more question since I have you and your wealth of knowledge here.  I was hoping to use `rarecurve()` to see whether I had taken enough counts in different land management types.  I currently have 5 types and 10 samples for each.  Is there a way (arguments) to use `rarecurve()` (editing the the function itself) so that each management type is a separate line in the output graph, or will I have to sum each management type (so I only have 5 rows, 1 for each type) and then run 'rarecurve()' on that edited dataframe?  Thanks.